# Is appending an iframe with data from an outside domain instead of making an AJAX call with it safe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I was trying to include a page from my domain into a product that my users will use, so an iframe seemed the best candidate, but there were issues when trying to AJAX-ify this to enchance performance - pull the whole iframe's data in an AJAX call.

But, as per CORS, loading content from another page is a big no-no, due to security reasons, so I can't have an AJAX call pull an HTML page from another domain to my customer's domain.

Great.

But `iframes` are fine. In fact, without them YouTube would be nowhere. So, my original code was:

```
<iframe src="link-to-documentation.com"></iframe>
```

But the problem was that every time I'd load my page, **I'd have to wait for that iframe to load too.**. It was 90% of my load time, for something that users will almost never click, so I had to make this "load only if needed" but if I were to pull the data from my link directly, I'd get this:

```
(index):1 Failed to load https://link.com: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1' is therefore not allowed access.
```

But an **iframe is safe, by its design and an iframe was what I needed.** And so I came up with actually reading the iframe HTML from a local file (on my domain), to bypass the security measures, like this:

```
    jQuery.ajax(
        {
            url: sprout_view_data.ABSPATH + '/iframe.txt', //Just a local link
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {
                frame_container.append(response);
            },

            error: function (response) {
                frame_container.append(response);
            }
        }
    );
```

And in my `iframe.txt`:

```
<iframe src="https://link.com"></iframe>
```

This would then get appended to my container and well, it works, no errors and life's good.

Or is it?

My concrete question: Is this a legitimate bypass or am I revoking security measures without knowing it?